# 'Cannot find module' error after clean `npm install` using a private registry (GitLab)

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

I get this error message `Cannot find module` when I run my NodeJS program after a successful `npm install`. This only happens for private modules.

I did `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`. I validated that the missing module is defined in package.json of my module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` needs to be run twice, first npm will install the private registry, then during the second install it will install the dependencies of the private registry. Make sure you commit `package-lock.json` to your project so when `npm install` is run the next time it will install from the list and you won't have to run it twice.